# Selected all rows with checkbox but for multiple tables displaying with a loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my application, I have several tables that are built with a loop.

```html
<div v-for="(dimension, index) in listQuestions" :key="index" :header="`${dimension.name}`">

            <table class="table-questions" >

                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" @click="onClickCheckAll(dimension)"  /></th>
                    <th>Sous-dimension</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody v-for="(question,i) in dimension.sousDimensions" >

                  <tr v-for="(item, p) in question.questions">

                  
                    <td v-if="item.barometre"><input type="checkbox" checked disabled :id="'choice-' + item.id"/></td>
                    <td v-else ><input type="checkbox" @click="onClickOneCheckbox(item.id)"  :id="'choice-' + item.id" /> </td>
                    <td style="width: 40%">{{question.name}}</td>
                    <td >{{item.item}}</td>

                  </tr>

                </tbody>

            </table>


          </div>
```

I would like to be able to select all the rows of each table with a checkbox.
I have seen this tuto: [vuejs tables and select all checkbox](https://vuejsexamples.com/vuejs-tables-and-select-all-checkbox/) which seems to me very good. But I can’t apply it in my case of several tables.

How can I use the data selected and selectAll like in the example but for several tables?

I have started to build a function to access the items like this and I have my ID of items :

EDIT.
I try to do this :

```js
    onClickCheckAll(value) { //when click to all chekckbox
      console.log("click")
      console.log(value)
      console.log(value.sousDimensions)

      for (var sousdim of value.sousDimensions)
      {
        for (var item of sousdim.questions)
        {
          console.log(this.selectCheck)

          const p = this.selectCheck.indexOf(item.id) //looking for index for each item

          const checkboxItem = document.querySelector("#choice-" + item.id) //all inputs with id choice-ID and then add or remove "checked" attribute

          if (p > -1) { //if still there, delete
            this.selectCheck.splice(p, 1);

            if (!item.barometre)
            {
              checkboxItem.checked=false
            }

          }
          else { //if not, adding in array
            this.selectCheck.push(item.id)
            checkboxItem.checked=true
          }

        }
      }
    },

    onClickOneCheckbox(val) {

      const index = this.selectCheck.indexOf(val);
      if (index > -1) //delete item if still in the array
      {
        this.selectCheck.splice(index, 1);
      }
      else
      {
        this.selectCheck.push(val)
      }

      console.log(this.selectCheck)
    }
```

And it's partially works : when I click individually on the first two rows of my table and then click on the checkbox to select all, all rows get selected...Except the first two!

See the problem here : https://jsfiddle.net/chtouk/rc80ksno/35/

Thanks for help

Comment: so you need a function to make all the checkboxes selected and also get the selected items' ids right?

Comment: I have severa Tables, that's the problem. I edit my message because I managed to start what I wanted but I can't finish: when I click individually on the first two rows of my table and then click on the checkbox to select all, all rows get selected...Except the first two! It's normal because of my code but I don't know how to do otherwise... Thanks for your help.